# Obtain one list of dictionaries out of a list containing list of dictionaries

Tags: list, dictionary

I have a list containing a list of dictionaries.

There are 29 different years, each year has 20 dictionaries where each dictionary constitutes one specific word field and contains words and each word has one value.

I want to have a dictionary for each word field in which each word has 29 values (one for each year).

So instead of

```
[[{'Apple': 0.4, 'Banana': 0.6}, {'Chocolate': 0.5, 'Chips': 0.5}],
[{'Apple': 0.6, 'Banana': 0.4}, {'Chocolate': 0.6, 'Chips': 0.4}],
[{'Apple': 0.8, 'Banana': 0.2}, {'Chocolate': 0.1, 'Chips': 0.9}]]
```

I want something like this:

```
[[{'Apple': [0.4, 0.6, 0.8], 'Banana': [0.6, 0.4, 0.2]}, {'Chocolate': [0.5, 0.6, 0.1], 'Chips': [0.5, 0.4, 0.9]}]
```

I've been trying for hours and wanted to use a `defaultdict` like

```
totaldict = defaultdict(list)
for d in (topics[0]): # create dictionary for first word field
    for key, value in d.items():
        totaldict[key].append(value)
```

but in that case the list `topics` would need to be structured like this:

```
[[{'Apple': 0.4, 'Banana': 0.6}, {'Apple': 0.6, 'Banana': 0.4}, {'Apple': 0.8, 'Banana': 0.2}], 
[{'Chocolate': 0.5, 'Chips': 0.5},{'Chocolate': 0.6, 'Chips': 0.4}, {'Chocolate': 0.1, 'Chips': 0.9}]]
```

There's probably an easy way to restructure my list but I have no idea how. How can I do that? Or maybe there is another way of achieving a single dictionary for each year containing multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforming the list can be done by using a numpy array.

```
topics = np.array(topics)

totaldict = defaultdict(list)
for d in (topics[:,0]): # create dictionary for first word field
    for key, value in d.items():
        totaldict[key].append(value)
```